# How do the spl_autoload_register do with array not function name?

Tags: php, laravel, spl-autoload-register

In Laravel's `AliasLoader`, it will register to `spl_autoload_register` like this:

```
spl_autoload_register([$this, 'load'], true, true);
```

What does `spl_autoload_register` do with the array `[$this, 'load']`?

Comment: Not sure what the question actually is, but if you're asking how that works, it's because the form `[$objectVar, 'methodName']` is [callable](https://www.php.net/callable). When it's called, it will run the `load` method from the passed (`$this` in your case) instance.

Comment: @Jonnix ,yes ,that 's what i want to ask ,thanks , now i know this is  kind of callable form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument of `spl_autoload_register` is a callable, as explained in the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php).

The [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) for the `callable`type says:

> A method of an instantiated object is passed as an array containing an object at index 0 and the method name at index 1. Accessing protected and private methods from within a class is allowed.

In the case for your question, `[$this, 'load']` refers to the method `load()` on the same class where `spl_autoload_register` is called.

E.g. something like this:

```php
class Foo {

  public function register() {

     spl_autoload_register([$this, 'load'], true, true);
  }

  public function load($className) {
     // do your loading
  }
}

$autoloader = new Foo();
$autoloader->register();
```